# Exposing almond module to window object fails due to asynchronicity

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, amd, almond

I am working on a JavaScript project where we use requirejs to manage our code. The product we create is to be used on 3rd party web sites, and therefore we cannot assume that an AMD compatible library is present. To solve this, we include [almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond) in our target file and expose our main module on `window`. The file created by our build looks like this:

```
(function() {
    //Almond lib

    //Our code

   define('window-exposer', ['main-module'], function(mainModule) {
       window.mainModule = mainModule;
   });

   require('window-exposer');
}());
```

When building a site that want to use `mainModule` an error is thrown because when the site specific code tries to access `window.mainModule` it has not been set yet. There are also cases where the module has indeed been initialized and the code works.

Is there any way to guarantee that the `window-exposer` is run before other JavascriptCode is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the solution provided here https://github.com/jrburke/almond#exporting-a-public-api